# How to put a rectangle on plyer's camera?

Tags: ios, python-3.x, kivy

I am playing around with Kivy on iOS and I wonder, whether it is possible to draw a rectangle on top of the camera view (something like when a QR code is scanned). This is a working demo on iPhone SE:

```
from kivy.app import App #for the main app
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout #the UI layout
from kivy.uix.label import Label #a label to show information
from plyer import camera #object to read the camera
from os.path import exists, join

class UI(FloatLayout):#the app ui
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lblCam = Label(text="Click to take a picture!") #create a label at the center
        self.add_widget(self.lblCam) #add the label at the screen

    def on_touch_down(self, e):
        
        camera.take_picture(join(App.get_running_app().user_data_dir, 'file_name.jpg'), self.done) #Take a picture and save at this location. After will call done() callback
        camera.print_me_something(x = None)
        
    def done(self, e): #receive e as the image location
        self.lblCam.text = e; #update the label to the image location

class Camera(App): #our app
    def build(self):
        ui = UI()# create the UI
        return ui #show it

    def on_pause(self):
        #when the app open the camera, it will need to pause this script. So we need to enable the pause mode with this method
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        #after close the camera, we need to resume our app.
        pass

Camera().run() #start our app
```

Comment: Try using the canvas.

Comment: It is not that easy, camera.take_picture pauses the kivy app and opens iOSCamera.